# MongoDB and Java: What's wrong with my update?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with the Java driver and have a Collection 'Questions' with the following format for each entry:

```
{
    "question" : "How are you?",
    "category" : "personal",
    "isTrain"   : true,
    "processed" : true
}
```

What I want to do is take every entry with both "processed" and "isTrain" equal to true, and I want to set their "processed" value to false. The code in which I'm trying to use for this is:

```
public void markUnprocessed(boolean isTrain) {
    BasicDBObject queryObj = new BasicDBObject();
    queryObj.put("processed", true);
    queryObj.put("isTrain",   isTrain);

    BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
    updateObj.put("processed", false);

    collection.updateMulti(queryObj, updateObj);
}
```

Calling this function from my code seems to have no effect, and I'm not sure why. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris Covert

Comment: You are calling it with isTrain set to true, right?

Comment: I actually call it with isTrain = false somewhere else as well, so as to mark those entries as unprocessed too, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a partial using $set, not a full update.
With current statement you would be losing all the other fields.

```
BasicDBObject updateObj = new BasicDBObject();
updateObj.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("processed", false));
```

Also note that you should turn on safe writes (using WriteConcern.SAFE) so that your app gets notified of any error from server.

Comment: Ah, I had seen the '$set' syntax online somewhere now that you mention it, but I definitely had no idea about how to make the Java representation for it. Thanks for the help!